# Import CSV file and append unique data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table ("Posts") that tracks social media data. I want to import a .csv file that contains the new data.

The .csv file, from an outside service, maintains a rolling three months of data.
I'd like to (1) open the .csv file, (2) identify each line, based on date, that doesn't exist in my "Posts" table, and then (3) import the data for the new line without changing data already in the table.

I've been digging through the forums but am not finding what I need.

For the import step, I'm trying:

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, TableName:="tblPosts", FileName:="C:\Users\[myname]\Desktop\Historical Reports\Posts.csv", HasFieldNames:=True
```

Unfortunately, I have somewhat different field names than column names. Do I need to skip the first line of the .csv and then build a custom SQL Insert statement?

Comment: The TransferText method can only do so much. Use it to import your file to a separate table and process that table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL query (as the MS Access engine can directly query CSV files) that runs the classic duplicate avoidance queries with [`NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/). Adjust below column names including *Date* accordingly:

```
INSERT INTO Posts (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3)
FROM [text;database=C:\Users\[myname]\Desktop\Historical Reports].Posts.csv AS t
LEFT JOIN Posts p
  ON t.Date = p.Date
WHERE p.Date IS NULL;


INSERT INTO Posts (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3)
FROM [text;database=C:\Users\[myname]\Desktop\Historical Reports].Posts.csv AS t
WHERE t.Date NOT IN
  (SELECT p.Date FROM Posts p);


INSERT INTO Posts (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3)
FROM [text;database=C:\Users\[myname]\Desktop\Historical Reports].Posts.csv AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM Posts p
   WHERE p.Date = t.Date);
```